# Do I need to declare methods of abstract class in respective interface?

Tags: java, methods, interface, abstract-class

In my application I have activities of 2 types, Hotel and Restaurant which I have implemented as abstract classes. I need to call a method which is on the HotelClass but the IDE tells me to create a method in abstractActivity. If I do this, it will create a duplicate method. How can I resolve this?

```
package pt;

public class HotelClass extends AbstractActivity {

    private int starClass;
    private int price; //preço medio por noite

    // Basic Account Constructor
    public HotelClass(String city, String name, String description, String address, int starClass, int price, String owner) {
        super(city, name, description, address, owner); // chamada construtor super-class
        this.starClass = starClass;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStar(){
        return this.starClass;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }

}
```

[image: My abstract class and super class below interface]

Comment: And what method is it that you have in common? Or methods? Just make an `interface` out of this/these method(s) and make your concrete class implement this interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class `AbstractActivity` is not `abstract`. This is why the IDE is asking you to implement those methods. If you declare it as abstract, then you won't have this problem.

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity implements ...
```

To make things clearer:

The abstract class `AbstractActivity` is a base class that will not be instantiated, it is there in order to put functionality that is common in the concrete classes `HotelClass` and `RestaurantClass`.
An abstract class does not need to have implemented all the methods declared by the interaces it implements. But a concrete class must provide implementation to all methods of the interfaces it implements. This is why `AbstractActivity` does not need to have implementation of all the methods declared by the interfaces it implements. But the concrete classes (the ones that are instantiated) need to know how they will implement the interface, so they need implementation for all methods. Some method implementations could be provided by their superclass.

Comment: Absolutely not. HotelClass and RestaurantClass are concrete (not abstract) classes. They are instantiated.

Comment: but now appear the same error, tell me to implement methos now on my concrete "HotelClass" and "RestaurantClass"

Comment: Yes, you must provide an implementation of these methods in the concrete classes. I will edit my answer to give you some more insight.

Comment: thanks a lot for edited explanation ! i fix it i change to concrete and interface tell me to add this methos, but i dont want this methos in 2 concrete class 

http://imageshack.us/a/img40/9199/semttuloamp.png

Comment: getFood() and getCost() are implemented differently by the two classes (Hotel and Restaurant), so you must have an implementation in both classes. If they had the same implementation, then you would be able to place it in the abstract base class (AbstractActivity). How could you avoid having the methods in both classes? Your classes do different things in these methods, so  you need two implementations. How could you avoid that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30709/discussion-between-alexandre-ferreira-and-nakosspy)

Answer (score 1):

Your class `AbstractActivity` is not declared as `abstract`.

Therefore, you are forced to implement all `interface` methods from top-hierarchy directly in this class.

You just have to declare as:

```
public abstract AbstractActivity implements ...
```

Comment: No, this is what an abstract class is supposed to be. A class that will not be instantiated, but it contains some common functionality for its concrete subclasses (HotelClass and RestaurantClass in your case).

Comment: if i change to abstract class apeear a error in

Activity activitys;
activitys = new RestaurantClass(...);

ERROR: "cannot instantiate the type"

Comment: `RestaurantClass` sounds like being abstract... since it's a typical error of trying to instantiate an abstract class. So, make it concrete.

Comment: i fix it i change to concrete and interface tell me to add this methos, but i dont want this methos in 2 concrete class 

http://imageshack.us/a/img40/9199/semttuloamp.png